# How to reverse search in Apple Mail Message Viewer

Tags: apple-mail

Using Apple Mail, if you have your inbox sorted by Date Received so that most recent messages are at the top of the inbox, you can type the beginning of someone's name and message viewer will automatially highlight / select the most recent message from that person.

However, if you have messages sorted so the most recent message at the bottom of your inbox, typing someone's  name automatically selects the oldest message from that person.

What could you do so that if you have your inbox sorted by Date Received with most recent at the bottom, typing someones name in message viewer would yield the newest, and not oldest, message from that person.